# Xamarin Forms - Media Plugin - Empty thumbnails on phone

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, media

I'm using James Montemagno´s media plugin to take photos.

For some reason, and only when running the application on my phone, when taking photos, thumbnails do appear correctly in TestFolder, but they appear as empty files.

Images appear correctly when running in the emulator.

This is my code:

```
 public async Task<MediaFile> TakePhoto() {
            MediaFile result = null;

            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable && CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported) {
                // Supply media options for saving our photo after it's taken.
                var mediaOptions = new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions {
                    SaveToAlbum = true,
                    Directory = "TestFolder",
                    Name="test.jpg"
                };

                // Take a photo of the business receipt.
                result = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(mediaOptions);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

**Edit 1:**

In short, for some reason the Media plugin doesn't work on my phone (Huawei P8 Lite). I've tried the sample on GitHub: (Usage)

```
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin
```

Photos do show in the emulator but don't on the phone (the camera opens and takes photos). As I mentioned above, if I access the  album folder empty thumbnails appear.

**Edit 2**

This is the android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="MediaPluginTests.Droid"></application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
</manifest>
```

Also I've added:

```
   var cameraStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);
            var storageStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);

            if (cameraStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted || storageStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted) {
                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Permission.Camera, Permission.Storage });
                cameraStatus = results[Permission.Camera];
                storageStatus = results[Permission.Storage];
            }
```

Both permissions return as granted.

**Edit 3**

I've tried on a Samsung Galaxy A3 and works perfectly, shows correctly in the camera roll and the app.

But this how images appear on my Huawei P8 phone's camera roll album:

[image]

**Edit 4**

I have tried on a different Huawei P8 Device and am getting the same problem.

Comment: The error is happening on both iOS and Android?

Comment: I'm only able to test it on Android.

Comment: Did you add the manifest permission ?

Comment: Yes I did, even though the permission is requested when running the application for the first time. ("Do you allow 'app1' to access the SD Card?")

Comment: What's the Android version you're running on the Huawei device?

Comment: I have the same issue,actually i recommend you to update your Xam.Plugin.Media to verson 2.3.0..i know maybe you have 2.6.2 but try 2.3.0 .try it and give me feedback  thanks

Comment: @Mike I downgraded to 2.3.0 but still no luck, thumbnails appear as empty and images aren't showing in the application.

Comment: @hankide I'm running Android versión 6.0

Comment: Can you post the logcat ouput here? Huawei P8 and some other similar models from Huawei seem to be somewhat problematic for programmers. If you don't see anything specific to your app on the logcat, dial `*#*#2846579#*#*` and go to Project Menu - Background Setting - Log setting and enable the logs and specify a logging level. This is Huawei specific and might not work on your model, but is worth to try.

Comment: I tried to post a logcat, but there was way too much information showing, I couldn't filter out only my apps.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem I set:

```
PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small
```

On StoreCameraMediaOptions:

```
var mediaOptions = new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions {
                    SaveToAlbum = true,
                    Directory = "MyDirectory",
                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small
                };
```

But instead of binding to AlbumPath I bind to Path:

Property from ViewModel(Using PRISM for Xamarin Forms):

```
public MediaFile Photo {
            get {
                return photo;
            }
            set {
                SetProperty<MediaFile>(ref photo, value);
            }
    }


<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Source="{Binding Photo.Path}"></Image>
```

I realised that if I added a Delay after the photo was taken:

```
await Task.Delay(5000)
```

Images would start to appear in the camera roll folder, but even then, the image didn't show on screen.

After looking at the output screen in Visual Studio, I noticed this message:

```
03-14 10:52:51.808 W/OpenGLRenderer(18106): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3120x4160, max=4096x4096)
```

I then realised that the problem was related to image size, but even setting the image size to small on StoreCameraMediaOptions , it made no difference.

It seems that resizing only applies to the internal application storage image and not the one stored in the camera roll folder.

Once the image is resized the photo shows correctly in the application.

Comment: It seems photo resizing with PhotoSize. Small is only applied to the photo located at the 'Path' property. After doing several tests it seems to only apply if SaveToAlbum is true.